# Reload UITabbarController when change selected index

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, custom-controls

I have a UITabBarController With the 2 Tabs. I want When I click on the Tab 2 (viewController B) then click on the Next button with navigationcontroller (viewController C). Then, I click Back button (custom button) to come back to Tab 1 (ViewController A) and I want when again I come back to Tab 2 the view controller should be display viewController B.

Thanks !

Comment: You shouldn't need to "reload" a tab view controller ever. The views for a tab view are pre-loaded when you first segue into the tab bar controller. It would be much more helpful if you posted sample code. What you're trying to explain is difficult to follow.

Answer (score 0):

On the custom button (Back button) action you should call popViewController and then jump to Tab 1. or when pressing on the Tab 2 you can check if you are in the root view controller of the navigationcontroller and if not put ViewController B as the root.